# Set username as argument

Tags: discord.py

Earlier, I asked a question which was fixing some broken code. But the code specified changed the role of the author.

```py
async def ruleBreak(ctx, arg):
    member = await ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="RuleBreakers")
    await discord.Member.add_roles(member, role)
```

However, I want to set a specified user to get the role, not the author. I've thought about removing the send part on line 2.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second line is saying that the member who should get the role is the member who invokes the command. For this you can use [`add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_role#discord.Member.add_roles) which takes the role you want to give as an arguments. You can specify a recipient and role like so `!addrole @someperson @thisrole`

```
@client.command()
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"I gave {user.name} the role {role.name}")
```